# How to control an Ubuntu PC from another Ubuntu PC over Internet, using mobile broadband connections?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina, ip

There are two Ubuntu PCs called **A** and **B**.
**A** and **B** are connected to the Internet using **two separated** Internet connections. (In my case, two **mobile broadband connections** <kbd>ppp0</kbd> x2 )
Each connection has a unique & static public IP address.

What I need is to control **A** computer's cursor, using **B** computer's mouse, over the **Internet**.

- In both computers, I have allowed other users to control my computer in **Desktop Sharing** preferences, as below:

  [image]
- When I try to connect to **A** from the **B** using **Remmina Remote Desktop Client**, it refuses to connect after trying for a while.
  These are my settings:

  [image]

## I expect this to be done from an available open source software, not from TeamViewer.

I found [this guide](http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/1/How+do+I+connect+to+another+computer+over+the+internet?) harder to understand.
Please provide me clear instructions...

## Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Each **Internet Connection** has its own IP address.  This is a **public** IP address.  The IP address assigned to each PC (or laptop) is a private address, on the private side of a **router**.  *Is the 'static IP' address you refer to for the PC or the Internet connection?*

Comment: According to your information, both public and private IP address are static. I think the Public IP is produced by the sim card inside my usb modem. But I'm not using a router, am I? I'm connecting to the Internet from a usb mobile broadband, in both computers.

Comment: Given that you are connecting through an USB modem, you may not have a private IP, just the public one. The mobile phone companies may be blocking the ports needed for VNC, 5800 and 5900. Can you check if the ports are open?

Comment: @david6 why wouldn't each intenret connection have its own ip address? And really all you need to know is the ip address of the host, whether it is public or internal depends on whether you are on a LAN, or a WAN.

Comment: IP according to **ifconfig** command : 10.225.5.115 (inet addr)

Comment: IP according to **www.whatismyip.com**  : 61.235.152.24

Comment: @user68186 : How can I open 5800 port...?

Comment: The **ifconfig** and **whatsmyip** shows you have an internal and an external IP. I am not sure where and how the transition is taking place without a router. The ports should be open when you enable desktop sharing. However, since you have two IPs the ports need to be forwarded like 61.235.152.24:5800 -> 10.255.5.115:5800. This is usually done at the router.

Comment: That's the point... That's why all the other guides didn't work for me... **I don't have a router...** Can't I do the forwarding from **iptables**?

Comment: I am afraid, this may be totally in the hands of your service provider. See http://www.broadbandgenie.co.uk/blog/20080513490/connect-to-xbox-live-with-a-usb-3g-modem . Can you search for "test firewall" in google and do some online port scans like https://www.securitymetrics.com/portscan.adp and see if ports 5800 and 5900 are open?

Comment: These ports are closed for my connection : 8080, 80, 5800, 5900 | I used this website to scan : http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/open-port-check.html (I hope this site is reliable..)

Comment: Can you please also provide details for both USB '3G/4G' modems, and ISP/Service providers.  ***That is probably where both the issues and solution needs to focus ..***

Comment: Can you check whether port 22 is closed or not. If not you can use VNC over ssh.

Comment: Port 22 is also closed as that site says... Is that site faking about ports? Why are my all ports closed..? This is my USB modem : **ONDA Communication S.p.A. ZTE MF636**

Comment: My service providers are Mobitel, Srilanka & Airtel Sri Lanka.

Comment: @Naveen Many service provider keeps these ports closed to prevent subscribers from running server type of activities using mobile data. The use of mobile data for servers "may not be allowed" as per their agreement document. The other reason is to keep the customers safe. Keeping the ports closed prevents hacking efforts. Are any ports open?

Comment: I understand... I'm lost... 
These pages says the exact thing you said:
http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=25894 

http://superuser.com/questions/397606/why-a-3g-router-wont-do-port-forwarding-when-on-3g-interface

Is there anything I have to ask from my ISP before I appriciate them??

What if I requirests them to eqalize my public and static ips? Or can I ask some sort of a ip to login to my modem?

Anyway, thanks user61186, your effort is much admired.. 
Can you please compile the final thoughts from all of your comments, so I have a reasonnable answer to offer the bounty...

Comment: @Naveen I wrote my anwser and then read the links. I think the accepted answer in http://superuser.com/questions/397606/why-a-3g-router-wont-do-port-forwarding-when-on-3g-interface is relevant for you as well. I am sorry, this is not going to work, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summarizing from comments**

The two computers are connected to the Internet by mobile (cell phone) data network. I will refer to the cell data service provider as the "Internet Service Provider" or **ISP**. There are **two** issues:

1. The ISP is providing the NAT (Network Address Translation) service
   such that the computer has an internal IP address and an external IP
   address with no apparent way to forward the ports of the external IP
   address to the internal IP address.
2. The ISP is also blocks all the useful ports of the external IP
   address.

I have no knowledge of the specific ISP in question. However, generally ISPs take these actions to prevent mobile data connections to be used to connect servers and for the security of the customers. Sometimes ISPs prohibit the use of mobile data for servers in their service agreements.

Under these circumstances,  specifically if the ISP service agreement prohibit the use of mobile data for servers, the ISP is unlikely to open the ports needed to connect the two computers and forward the specific ports from the external IP address to the internal IP address.

**Your connections will work If the ISP:**

(a) opens the ports

(b) and do either of the two following:

1. forwards the open ports from the external IP to the NATed internal
   IP, or
2. provides you with a real IP, not a NATed one (See the quote from
   superuser below)

**Without these from the ISP it is impossible to use the native solution to remotely connect from computer B to computer A.**

About conversion from NATed setup to real static IP setup from [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/397606/why-a-3g-router-wont-do-port-forwarding-when-on-3g-interface):

> The problem lies on what address you are given, most of the time it's
>   already a NATed IP. However, many carriers can switch you to a real
>   "external" IP - which is generally used for VPN because sometimes NAT
>   can interfere with VPN (assuming you can get past the CSRs). However,
>   even though this would be a publicly addressable IP - I imagine that
>   they would still put in restrictions/firewall to prevent you from
>   doing exactly what you are trying to do.

If the ISP is agreeable to opening and forwarding ports, the I recommend using VNC over ssh tunnel for the following reasons:

1. VNC over ssh will require opening (and forwarding) of port 22 only (or some other port set by the user).
2. VNC over ssh is a more secure method where the data transmitted over
   the mobile system is encrypted.
3. ssh can be set up to use public/private keys instead of passwords,
   which is much more difficult for hackers to crack.

To try this in Remmina, go to the `ssh` tab and check the two checkboxes, (a) use ssh, and (b) use tunnel. You may have to install ssh in both the computers.

However, this solution is not available without port forwarding in NATed IP setup or a setup with direct access to the external IP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Install  Team Viewer application  on both Ubuntu systems. You can view and control systems in bidirectional.

TightVNC is a opensource remote control software package. With TightVNC, you can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it. You can get it [here](http://www.tightvnc.com/). You need to configure router

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using it.... I want it to be done using an open source software

Comment: Sadly, teamviewer is the easiest way to do what you want without having to reconfigure your router. :(

Comment: Which router/dsl modem you are using? All you have done is right but just little configuration from your  dsl modem/router is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Forgettaboutit! You've done nothing wrong. You are just geting NATed by your mobile providers. On both ends. with no control over the routers. That's *the* worst case imaginable.

I recommend splitting your question in two:

1. How can you get *any* connection running between the machines.
2. If you got that far, you can see how to get a desktop connection.

I recommend starting out with ssh. Connecting these two Computers is probably going to involve some ssh tunneling. It would be *very* good to have a third party with a public internet address. I.e. some cheap 2€/month VServer.

Best would be to have a vpn solution. This is a bit tougher for starters, but more convenient in the long run.

Sorry. There is no easy answer for you. You either have to dig network tunnels or get a serious internet connection. Choose one. This may sound rude, but believe me, I'm just the messenger of bad news here. Please don't vote me down.

Here is some lecture for further reading about your problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Drawbacks

Note the phrase: `Hosts behind NAT-enabled routers do not have end-to-end connectivity and cannot participate in some Internet protocols.`

Any solution anyone can come up with here *will* involve a third party. Be careful about using proprietary web services.

Comment: Oh and also: If you see any proprietary software doing this, then rest assured that this proprietary software is using a proprietary internet service to function. A STUN gateway at best,  a router, able to listen in to your traffic at worst (I'm not saying "*they*" are after you, just that "*they*" had an easyer job if they were ;-). In any case this makes you even more dependent on the proprietor. The problem is fundamental with Internet-Routing.

Comment: The concept of beating a firewall is called "NAT busting."  I saw an interesting solution called pwnat a while back.  See if you can find anything useful.

Comment: @gh403: I actually hope that naveen will rephrase the question, since NAT traversal is way beyond the scope of this thread.

Comment: aaa... wats rephrasing? I have no idea.. :(

Comment: what i said, split the question.. or "alter the phrase, the wording" to be less question at once.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in helping to friend the `easiest` way to remote someone ubuntu desktop is to install google chrome remote desktop extension.
Link to extension

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp

video tutorial

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2RBIkEgRk0&feature=related

  We tried it with friend who has win 7 it works great.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it in the real way. (From Ubuntu's inbuilt client)

Answer (score 1):

I use KRDC/KRFB (Client/Server) to use VNC-related stuff. Searching for VNC software (both clients/viewers and servers) will help you find other free alternatives (like TightVNC, I think).

**EDIT:** Searching for VNC software is easier with Synaptic Package Manager than it is with Ubuntu Software Center, but both should yield interesting results.

**EDIT #2:** You must keep the preference windows open! These also hold the server online as far as I can tell, but this may have been fixed since I last used the software screenshotted above

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the Hamachi Beta client from Log-me in on both Ubuntu machines and connect them to your Hamachi network.

You can then use VNC to achieve remote control over VPN. This is not open source though.